# MySQL Mostrar datos de una tabla relacionada consigo misma

Tags: mysql, join

Tengo una tabla "categoria" con los datos:

```
cod_categoria | categoria | categoria_padre
1 | tv | 0
2 | led | 1
3 | lcd | 1
```

¿Es posible hacer una consulta mysql que me devuelva esa tabla de la siguiente manera?

```
cod_categoria | categoria | categoria_padre
1 | tv | -
2 | led | tv
3 | lcd | tv
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Intentaste algo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

esto deberia funcionar, nota el uso de los alias

```
SELECT categorias.cod_categoria, categorias.nombre, cat.nombre 
FROM categorias 
JOIN categorias as cat 
ON categorias.categoria_padre = cat.cod_categoria
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder! Comparto el código que enviaste adaptando un poco

`SELECT c1.cod_categoria, c1.categoria, c2.categoria FROM categoria as c1 LEFT JOIN categoria as c2 ON c1.categoria_padre = c2.cod_categoria `

y **funcionó tal como quería**. Muchas gracias nuevamente.

Comment: sin un left join, esto no funciona...

Comment: @gbianchi cuando lo simule me funciono sin el left join y tambien con el left join, no note diferencia

Comment: Habria que ver tu simulacion, pero si categoria_padre =0 entonces no hay registros para joinear y no trae nada. Aunque habria que ver en que entorno lo simulaste, mysql a veces se comporta de forma no standard.

Comment: tienes razon, cuando lo simule no habian categoria_padre 0 o Null, se me paso.. osea todas tenian algun valor

Comment: @gbianchi  Agregué **left join** porque así muestra también las categorias que considero "padre", sin left join muestran solamente las "subcategorias". Luego en mi archivo php voy a colocar un **if** donde si el valor es "Null", muestre un "-"

Comment: @HViveros aunque no esta mal, no necesitas hacer eso. Mi respuesta tiene un left join. Fijate como funciona el sitio, no agregues una respuesta en los comentarios, acepta la respuesta que te funciono. Si queres, deja un comentario en mi respuesta respecto a eso que queres hacer, y modificamos la misma para agregar eso

Answer (score 1):

Esto es una tabla que se relaciona con si misma.

Lo que tratas de hacer se soluciona con un left join (el left es importante aca) consigo misma.

```
select cod_categoria, a.categoria, b.categoria as categoria_padre
from  categoria a left join categoria on a.cod_categoria = b.categoria_padre
```

Porque si ves ahi, estamos diciendole que traiga todo lo de la tabla que esta a la izquierda y solo lo de la derecha relacionado.

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder! Efectivamente en el comando **left join** está la clave.

Comparto el sql formulado en base a las dos respuestas que obtuve, y funcionó perfecto!

`SELECT c1.cod_categoria, c1.categoria, c2.categoria FROM categoria as c1 LEFT JOIN categoria as c2 ON c1.categoria_padre = c2.cod_categoria`

Comment: Gracias por los consejos. Saludos.

Comment: @hviveros no entiendo por que aceptaste una respuesta que esta mal :/. Dicho por el mismo usuario, y que ni siquiera arreglo.

Comment: Acepté porque es la que más se acercó a lo que quería, y con tu explicación pude adaptar y me funcionó (respuesta que coloqué en los comentarios). De igual forma agradezco ambas respuestas.